# Using Optional Enum as a method argument

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's say there is some `CalculatorFactory` that returns specific calculators based on a `CalculationType` `enum`.

Let's also say that there is a requirement for some default behavior if a specific `CalculatorType` is not defined.

What are the tradeoffs between the following interfaces for this `CalculatorFactory`:

- A `getCalculator` method that takes a non-null `CalculatorType` argument with a `DEFAULT` `CalculatorType` enum value
- A `getSpecificCalculator` method that takes a non-null `CalculatorType` argument (no `DEFAULT` `CalculatorType` enum value), as well as a `getDefaultCalculator` method that takes no arguments
- A `getCalculator` method that takes a non-null `Optional<CalculatorType>` argument (no `DEFAULT` `CalculatorType` enum value)

Comment: "Preferred interface" is just a matter of opinion. Opinion-based questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, sorry

Comment: I would avoid a `DEFAULT` enum value since it would require any code doing a `switch` to handle the `DEFAULT` case even though that's not an actual type of calculator. How to create a default calculator is a problem for the factory API to solve; it shouldn't leak into the enum.

Comment: @Michael understood - I've updated the language to remove the term "preferred interface".

Comment: You aren't really supposed to take `Optional<T>` as an argument for anything. This type is added to serve as a return value of the method, not as input value.

Comment: Despite the language edit wouldn't it still be a matter of preferences and expectations? What would you want to happen in the case of a default enum value? I'm thinking that the handling of the default enum value and the Optional<CalculatorType> argument would be pretty similar, so in reality there wouldn't be much of a difference. It's also intended to be used for return types, not input types. I would say that your class should not leave much to the imagination or surprise its consumers. I prefer my classes to be obvious and self documenting.