# "Default" enum value, global variable or part of enum

Tags: c, enums

Alrighty bear with me. I have an application where I have some mutually exclusive enumeration. For convenience I also provided a "default" that acted as part of the `enum`, which was previously statically determined at configure-time with a macro.

```c
typedef enum {
  FRUIT_APPLE,
  FRUIT_ORANGE,
  FRUIT_PEAR
} Fruit;

#if defined(HAVE_APPLES)
#  define FRUIT_DEFAULT FRUIT_APPLE
#elif defined(HAVE_ORANGES)
#  define FRUIT_DEFAULT FRUIT_ORANGE
#else
#  define FRUIT_DEFAULT FRUIT_PEAR
#endif

void foo(Fruit f)
{
  switch(f) {
    case FRUIT_APPLE:
      // etc...
  }
}
```

I am now adding a feature whereby the user can change the default at runtime via some `SetDefaultFruit()` function, but I am a bit torn on the best long-term way of implementing this.

---

### Add it to the enum directly

I would also need an internal helper function convert the value.

```c
// Fruit_private.c
Fruit private_default;

Fruit convert_default(Fruit f) 
{
  if (f == FRUIT_DEFAULT) f = private_default;
  return f;
}
```

Which would need to be used like so:

```c
typedef enum {
  FRUIT_APPLE,
  FRUIT_ORANGE,
  FRUIT_PEAR,
  FRUIT_DEFAULT
} Fruit;

void foo(Fruit f)
{
  switch(convert_default(f)) {
    case FRUIT_APPLE:
      // etc...
  }
}
```

Pros:

- The value is still statically determined by compiler.
- The value is constant, and user cannot change it (without going through the proper access function).
- Less chance the user fumbles the call by passing an out-of-bounds value (I can simply check `FRUIT_APPLE < f <= FRUIT_DEFAULT`).

Cons:

- Devs must remember to call extra conversion step.
- Users cannot check if the "default" is equal to some specific `Fruit` without an extra function.

---

### Global Variable

Instead of adding to enum, it simply lives as a global variable

```c
typedef enum {
  FRUIT_APPLE,
  FRUIT_ORANGE,
  FRUIT_PEAR
} Fruit;

extern Fruit FRUIT_DEFAULT;

void foo(Fruit f)
{
  switch(f) {
    case FRUIT_APPLE:
      // etc...
  }
}
```

Pros:

- Devs cannot forget to convert the value.
- Trivial for users to check what the default is, i.e. `FRUIT_DEFAULT == FRUIT_APPLE` works exactly as expected.

Cons:

- Since it is a non-`const` global, the value could be changed from anywhere at any time (including by the user) without the library knowing about it, so it may be difficult to error-check it.
- global variables are generally speaking un-optimizable and may inhibit other optimizations (they could hold any value at any time, and any pointer could alias them)<sup>[1]</sup>.

<sup>[1]</sup>: Before you get your pitchforks out about premature optimization, yes I understand. By including this point in the cons section I am not implying this is *the biggest deal in the world*, just that it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: Paraphrasing [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263763/using-optional-enum-as-a-method-argument#comment127670564_72263763): I would avoid a `DEFAULT` enum value since it would require any code doing a switch to handle the `DEFAULT` case even though that's not an actual type of fruit. Controlling the default fruit is best solved with a global variable or function; it shouldn't leak into the enum.

Comment: The second way is clearly better. Any performance impact of using the global variable is swamped by the function call overhead of `convert_default()`, or the comparison overhead if the function call is inlined.

Comment: The thing I am most worried about in the global variable case is error checking the enum value. In reality this `enum` is commonly used internally as an index into arrays (i.e. `my_array[my_fruit]`) or some other data structure. I agree the global is the "cleanest" solution but would like to afford myself and other devs as much protection from footguns as possible.

Comment: I do not understand, why are you writing here. Yes, there are these two approaches, yes they have pros and cons. In the spirit of this forum, what is your question?

Comment: What does error checking the enum value mean? What footguns are you referring to?

Comment: Do you want all variables set to the default to get new values whenever the default fruit is changed, or do you want them to retain their old values?

Comment: @JohnKugelman the value passed to `foo()` for example being outside of the `enum` bounds.

Comment: @JohnKugelman In reality the `Fruit` `enum` here is used in deciding how to construct an instance of another data structure (lets call them `FruitBasket`). Each `FruitBasket` is disjoint and doesn't share state with other `FruitBasket`s. So I don't need to worry about previous values of `FRUIT_DEFAULT`.

Comment: What I'm getting at is there's a subtle behavioral difference between the two approaches. With `FRUIT_DEFAULT` any variables will take on the new default whenever it's changed, whereas with a global variable they'll stay at the previous default. That might or might not actually matter to you. Just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: @JohnKugelman hmmm good point, though they both somewhat suffer from this problem (an unwitting user could simply store the return of the conversion function in a variable).